# Shooting a bullet in motion

Tags: kinematics, inertial-frames, projectile, drag, speed

If a bullet is shot from a firearm from a moving car in the direction of movement, would the speed gained with respect to the car be same as the speed of a bullet that is shot from an immobile gun?
I’m talking solely about the speed at the muzzle exit.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about [Galileo's Parable of the Ship](http://www.visualrelativity.com/LIGHTCONE/galileo.html).

There will be no difference. The gun will work just the same whether moving or not.

Answer (score -1):

The relative speed of the bullet to the gun would almost certainly be slower in the moving case because of the greater incoming air resistance opposing the acceleration of the round in the barrel. This may be a very small effect in practice though.

Comment: Is air resistance the only factor? What about energy conservation? Since it’s proportional to velocity squared, it would take a lot of energy to gain same velocity at a higher car speed, right?

Comment: I didn't know your uncertainty was related to energy conservation.  If we are talking strictly from the point of view of someone in the car, the car and gun and bullet before it's fired all have zero velocity and zero kinetic energy. Then the bullet acquires some kinetic energy $E$ when fired. From the perspective of someone on the roadside, the car and gun and bullet start with some kinetic energy $E_1$ and the bullet then acquires $E$ energy on top of that from being fired.

Comment: In both cases, the *difference* between the bullet's energy before and after firing is $E$, and this energy comes from the propellant.

Comment: I've *neglected* the air resistance in this example

Comment: I think neglecting air resistance (really *increased air density*, since there isn't going to be any wind inside the barrel, just increased pressure) is the only reasonable approach. The effect will be so incredibly small as to be on the same tiny scale as all the other things we're happy to ignore - centrifugal force vis-a-vis Earth's rotation, the Coriolis Effect, probably Bernoulli's principle (the explosives probably work slightly differently at different ambient pressures), wind chill (cooler gun barrels are smaller)...